# Relationship between pickle and deepcopy

Tags: python, pickle, python-2.x, deep-copy

*What exactly is the relationship between `pickle` and `copy.deepcopy`*?  What mechanisms do they share, and how?

It is clear the two are closely-related operations, and share some of the mechanisms/protocols, but I can't wrap my head around the details.

Some (confusing) things I found out:

1. If a class defines `__[gs]etstate__`, they get called upon a `deepcopy` of its instances.  This surprised me at first, because I thought they are specific to `pickle`, but then I found that *[Classes can use the same interfaces to control copying that they use to control pickling](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)*. However, there's no documentation of *how* `__[gs]etstate__` is used when deepcopying (how the value returned from `__getstate__` is used, what is being passed to `__setstate__`?)
2. A naive alternative implementation of `deepcopy` would be `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(obj))`.  However, this can't possibly be equivalent to deepcopy'ing, because if a class defines a `__deepcopy__` operation, it would not be invoked using this pickle-based implementation of deepcopy.  (I also stumbled upon a statement that deepcopy is more general than pickle, and there are many types which are deepcopyable, but not pickleable.)

(1) indicates a commonality, while (2) indicates a difference between `pickle` and `deepcopy`.

On top of that, I found these two contradictory statements:

> [copy_reg](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy_reg.html): The pickle, cPickle, and copy modules use those functions when pickling/copying those objects

and

> The [copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module does not use the copy_reg registration module

This, on one hand, is another indication of a relationship/commonality between `pickle` and `deepcopy`, and on the other hand, contributes to the my confusion...

*[My experience is with python2.7, but I'd also appreciate any pointers regarding the differences in pickle/deepcopy between python2 and python3]*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not be confused by (1) and (2).  In general, Python tries to include sensible fall-backs for missing methods.  (For instance, it is enough to define `__getitem__` in order to have an iterable class, but it may be more efficient to also implement `__iter__`.  Similar for operations like `__add__`, with optional `__iadd__` etc.)

`__deepcopy__` is the most specialized method that `deepcopy()` will look for, but if it does not exists, falling back to the pickle protocol is a sensible thing to do.  It does not really call `dumps()`/`loads()`, because it does not rely on the intermediate representation to be a string, but it will indirectly make use of `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` (via `__reduce__`), as you observed.

Currently, [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) still states

> … The copy module does not use the copy_reg registration module.

but that seems to be [a bug that has been fixed in the meantime](http://bugs.python.org/issue11481) (possibly, the 2.7 branch has not gotten enough attention here).

Also note that this is pretty deeply integrated into Python (at least nowadays); the `object` class itself implements `__reduce__` (and its versioned _ex variant), which refers to `copy_reg.__newobj__` for creating fresh instances of the given object-derived class.

Comment: Oh, and the only difference I know here between Python 2 and 3 is the `copy_reg` module to be renamed to `copyreg`.

Comment: Uhh, no.  You're kinda wrong.  `deepcopy` actually doesn't use `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`.  `deepcopy` uses `__deepcopy__`, pickle's dispatch_table, `__reduce__` and `__reduce_ex__`… in that order.  Check the code.  http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/copy.py

Comment: `__reduce__` and `__reduce_ex__` can call `__setstate__` and `__getstate__`.  However, they don't have to.

Comment: My wording might've been confusing; I just never implemented `__reduce__` myself, but found `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` much easier to use.  (And/or, `__getinitargs__` / `__getnewargs__`.)

Comment: I'd like people downvoting this to leave a reason as a comment – I don't see anything wrong with my answer; reading through the discussion again and my answer (which I obviously edited for clarification long ago), I am still quite happy with it.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I had to read the source code for this one, but it looks like it's a pretty simple answer.
http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/copy.py

`copy` looks up some of the builtin types it knows what the constructors look like for (registered in the `_copy_dispatch` dictionary, and when it doesn't know how to copy the basic type, it imports `copy_reg.dispatch_table`... which is the place where `pickle` registers the methods it knows for producing new copies of objects.  Essentially, it's a dictionary of the type of object and the "function to produce a new object" -- this "function to produce a new object" is pretty much what you write when you write a `__reduce__` or a `__reduce_ex__` method for an object (and if one of those is missing or needs help, it defers to the `__setstate__`, `__getstate__`, etc methods.

So that's `copy`.  Basically… (with some additional clauses…)

```
def copy(x):
    """Shallow copy operation on arbitrary Python objects.

    See the module's __doc__ string for more info.
    """

    cls = type(x)

    copier = _copy_dispatch.get(cls)
    if copier:
        return copier(x)

    copier = getattr(cls, "__copy__", None)
    if copier:
        return copier(x)

    reductor = dispatch_table.get(cls)
    if reductor:
        rv = reductor(x)
    else:
        reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce_ex__", None)
        if reductor:
            rv = reductor(2)
        else:
            reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce__", None)
            if reductor:
                rv = reductor()
            else:
                raise Error("un(shallow)copyable object of type %s" % cls)
```

`deepcopy` does the same thing as the above, but in addition inspects each object and makes sure that there's a copy for each new object and not a pointer reference.  `deepcopy` builds it's own `_deepcopy_dispatch` table (a dict) where it registers functions that ensure the new objects produced do not have pointer references to the originals (possibly generated with the `__reduce__` functions registered in `copy_reg.dispatch_table`)

Hence writing a `__reduce__` method (or similar) and registering it with `copy_reg`, should enable `copy` and `deepcopy` to do their thing as well.

Comment: so it seems like "copy does not use copy_reg" is sort of a lie.  It uses it under the covers. :)