# make a truly deep copy of a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, deep-copy

I have a `pd.Series` with each cell being a list.
I want to make a deep copy of it, however it seems like [`pd.Series.copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.copy.html) only creates a shallow copy of the values (even though the `deep` arg is `True` be default).

example

```
import pandas as pd

sr = pd.Series([list(range(3)), list(range(3))])
sr_c = sr.copy()
sr[0].append(4)
```

the copied `pd.Series` `sr_c` is being transformed to

```
0   [0, 1, 2, 4]
1   [0, 1, 2]
```

I did this and it worked:

```
from copy import deepcopy
sr_c = sr_c.apply(deepcopy)
```

however this seems like a hack, is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Seems like this is expected. `When deep=True, data is copied but actual Python objects will not be copied recursively, only the reference to the object. This is in contrast to copy.deepcopy in the Standard Library, which recursively copies object data (see examples below).` So you don't actually deepcopy the lists, which are mutable so it propagates to both `Series`. (This is the last example on the documentation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard *hacky* way of deep-copying python objects should work.  That is, using `pickle`.

```
import pickle
sr2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(sr))
```

Comment: Would break if some values of the index or entries are not serializable.

Comment: @Learningisamess, correct. That is why this is a hack, but a *fairly useful one*. Pickling+unpickling and deepcopying operations are similar and related, though not equivalent.  Although rare, there are types which are deepcopy-able and not pickle-able.  More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22388854/2096752)

Answer (score 4):

I have used

```py
from copy import deepcopy
sr_copy = pd.Series( deepcopy(sr.to_dict()))
```

just to be sure that the index is copied recursively too (if needed).