# Deep copy of Pandas dataframes and dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, copy

I'm creating a small Pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'colA': [["a", "b", "c"]]})
```

I take a deepcopy of that df. I'm not using the Pandas method but general Python, right?

```
import copy
df_copy = copy.deepcopy(df)
```

A df_copy.head() gives the following:

[image]

Then I put these values into a dictionary:

```
mydict = df_copy.to_dict()
```

That dictionary looks like this:

[image]

Finally, I remove one item of the list:

```
mydict['colA'][0].remove("b")
```

I'm surprized that the values in df_copy are updated. I'm **very confused** that the values in the original dataframe are updated too! Both dataframes look like this now:

[image]

I understand Pandas doesn't really do deepcopy, but this wasn't a Pandas method. My questions are:

1) how can I build a dictionary from a dataframe that doesn't update the dataframe?

2) how can I take a copy of a dataframe which would be completely independent?

thanks for your help!

Cheers,
Nicolas

Comment: Did you try to do a deepcopy of the dictionary instead of the dataframe?

Comment: @Nicolas if you are satisfied with answer - it would be great if you can mark an answer as correct. If you still have some questions - fill free to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: Thanks Stas, perfect, works like I hoped !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### TLDR

To get deepcopy:
`df_copy = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns, data = copy.deepcopy(df.values))`

#### Disclaimer

---

Notice that [putting mutable objects inside a DataFrame can be an antipattern](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17406#issuecomment-326455980) so make sure that you really need it and you understand what you are doing.

#### Why doesn't your copy independent

---

When applied on an object, copy.deepcopy is [looked up for a _*deepcopy*_ method of that object, that is called in turn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy). It's added to avoid copying too much for objects. In the case of a DataFrame instance [in version 0.20.0 and above - _*deepcopy*_ doesn`t work recursively](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/0b4fdf988e3125f7c55aaf6e08a2dfa7d9e2e8a0).

Similarly, if you will use `DataFrame.copy(deep=True)` [deep copy will copy the data, but will not do so recursively.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) .

#### How to solve the problem

---

To take a truly deep copy of a DataFrame containing a list(or other python objects), so that it will be independent - you can use one of the methods below.

```
df_copy = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns, data = copy.deepcopy(df.values))
```

For a dictionary, you may use same trick:

```
mydict = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns, data = copy.deepcopy(df_copy.values)).to_dict()
mydict['colA'][0].remove("b")
```

[There's also a standard hacky way of deep-copying python objects:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708341/make-a-truly-deep-copy-of-a-pandas-series)

```
import pickle
df_copy = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(df))
```

Feel free to ask for any clarifications, if needed.