# Why do changes on pandas df.copy() affect original df

Tags: python, pandas

I thought that working on a copy of a pandas df didn't change the original df... However, in this example, it does:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"first": [[1,2,3], [4,2,5], [6,2,7]]})
a = test.copy()
s = a.sample()
s = s["first"].iloc[0]
s.remove(2)
```

When I now print test again, it has changed. Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59683237/deep-copy-of-pandas-dataframes-and-dictionaries

Comment: An explanation can also be found at the very end of the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html).