# Truly deep copying Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deep-copy

I came across something i find very odd: Apparently it is not possible, to truly deep copy pandas dataframes.

I would expect, that if i create a deep copy of a dataframe, and i modify data in this copy, it has not effect on the original dataframe. But apparently this is not the case, or even possible if i'm not wrong.

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sets':set([1,2])}, index=[0])

def pop(df_in):
    df = df_in.copy()
    print(df['sets'].apply(lambda x: set([x.pop()])))

pop(df)
pop(df)
pop(df)

>>> KeyError: 'pop from an empty set'
```

or

```
import copy
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sets':set([1,2])}, index=[0])

def pop(df_in):
    df = copy.deepcopy(df_in)
    print(df['sets'].apply(lambda x: set([x.pop()])))

pop(df)
pop(df)
pop(df)

>>> KeyError: 'pop from an empty set'
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to create true deep copies of pandas dataframes?
2. If not why? if yes, how?

Comment: As an aside, it is very strange to have sets inside a dataframe.

Comment: In-depth answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59684662/8502312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to convert `df_in` to Python dictionary which works better with `copy`:

```
def pop(df_in):
    df = pd.DataFrame(copy.deepcopy(df_in.to_dict()) )
    print(df['sets'].apply(lambda x: set([x.pop()])))

for i in range(3): pop(df)
```

Output:

```
0    {1}
Name: sets, dtype: object
0    {1}
Name: sets, dtype: object
0    {1}
Name: sets, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your objects are **mutable** as they are sets. The [documents](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) explicitly call out this behavior with a warning (emphasis my own):

> When deep=True, data is copied **but actual Python objects will not be copied recursively**, only the reference to the object.

So as always with references to mutable objects, if you change it it affects it everywhere. We can see for ourselves despite the deep copy the objects have the same ID.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'sets': [{1,2}]}, index=[0])
df1 = df.copy(deep=True)

id(df['sets'].iloc[0])
#4592957024

id1(df['sets'].iloc[0])
#4592957024
```

Comment: And why does `copy.deepcopy` not work for Pandas dataframes? The docs there say: "A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original."