# Deepcopy for instances of class inheriting from Counter vs dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, counter

I am writing custom classes that inherit either from the Python class `dict`, or `collections.Counter` and I am facing problem with the behaviour of `deepcopy`. The problem is basically that `deepcopy` works as intended when inheriting from `dict` but not from `Counter`.

Here is an example:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from collections import Counter

class MyCounter(Counter):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo


c = MyCounter(0)
assert c.foo == 0  # Success
c1 = deepcopy(c)
assert c1.foo == 0  # Failure


d = MyDict(0)
assert d.foo == 0  # Success
d1 = deepcopy(d)
assert d1.foo == 0  # Success
```

I am a bit clueless as to why this is happening given that the source code of the `Counter` class does not seem to change anything about the deepcopy (no custom `__deepcopy__` method for instance).

I understand that I may have to write a custom `__deepcopy__` method but it's not clear to me how to. In general I would rather not have to do that given that it works perfectly for `dict`.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: An interesting thing to note is that at your `# Failure` line, `c1.foo == {}`. This is likely a useful clue.

Comment: Note that `copy` doesn't work for `MyCounter`, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`deepcopy` has several fallbacks, covered in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388854/relationship-between-pickle-and-deepcopy)

In this case, your particular base class `Counter` specialize pickle serialization, which is what `deepcopy` will pick up on (as the second option, as no specialization for `__deepcopy__` happens to exist).

If you step through the code in a debugger, you'll find it ends up at Counter's `__reduce__` method, where the python 3.9 implementation of `Counter` has:

```py
    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (dict(self),)
```

where we see can see where information is lost as `Counter`'s implementation here relies on that there aren't any other fields stored in this object other than the dictionary part itself.

You could overload `__reduce__` or `__reduce_ex__`, which would fix pickling and as a bonus also fix deepcopy, or you could overload `__deepcopy__` and provide the necessary implementation for it.

Implementing our own deepcopy isn't to complex, and we can keep the code very simple:

```py
class MyCounter(Counter):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        copy_instance = MyCounter(deepcopy(self.foo, memo))
        for key, val in self.items():
            copy_instance[deepcopy(key, memo)] = val  # val is just an int
        return copy_instance

c = MyCounter(123)
c['deep'] = 1
c['copy'] = 2

c1 = deepcopy(c)
assert c1.foo == c.foo
assert c1['deep'] == c['deep']
assert c1['copy'] == c['copy']
```

(In most cases I would probably recommend against overloading Counter or dict in order to add more attributes to them, but rather compose a custom class that *has* a counter or dict instance variable instead.)

Comment: Was 'meh' about Your answer until I saw 'prefer composition over inheritance'. +1

Comment: That's a very helpful answer! Thanks a lot, I did not get the link between deepcopy and pickle.

About composition vs inheritance, maybe I should have gone that way from the beginning indeed.

Comment: @Siolan The same way `str(x)` will use `__str__` if it exists and fallback to `__repr__`, `deepcopy` looks for `__deepcopy__` but falls back to `__reduce__/__reduce_ex__` as a second option and use that to serialize + deserialize the object (this is what pickle uses), which will work as a deep copy but might be less efficient. Even if you implement `__deepcopy__` for your custom class, it would still fail to pickle properly, unless you also fix `__reduce__`.

Comment: I see, I did not know the link between `deepcopy` and `__reduce__`. Well I've now implemented the reduce method and all works perfectly! Thanks :)